# Array Concatenation in Shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop, concatenation

I made an attempt for a simple shell script to view statefulset's images, and then replace them if desired.

I ran into this issue that the array values that are stored are not getting displayed properly..
here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
##-chronograph3r
##Variables 

read -p "Namespace : " NS

##### To find the Image tags in statefulset 

app=($(kubectl get statefulset -n $NS -o=name | grep "myapp" | cut -c 18-) )
declare app
imgver=($(kubectl get statefulset -n $NS ${array[@]} -o yaml | egrep "image: asia.gcr.io" ))
declare imgver

#--- To display current image version
for i in $@
do
    app[${#app[@]}]=$i
    imglist[${#imgver[@]}]=$i
    echo $i
done
for  (( i==0; i < ${#app[@]}; i++  ))
do
    echo "current image version for ${app[$i]} is ${imgver[$i]}" 
done
```

the desired output should be,

```
current image version for myapp1 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:latest
current image version for myapp2 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:1.4.2
current image version for myapp3 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:1.3.0
current image version for myapp4 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:stable
```

the output I get is

```
current image version for myapp1 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:latest
current image version for myapp2 is image: 
current image version for myapp3 is image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:1.3.0
current image version for myapp4 is image:
```

When I do " echo ${imgver[@]}"

it returns this

```
image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:latest  image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:1.4.2  image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:1.3.0  image: asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp:stable
```

I believe that concatenating the declared arrays is the troublemaker here. 
help me find the issue here or let me know if there are other ways to achieve the desired output.

Comment: First, quote your variables. Especially `${array[@]}` and `$@` should be `"${array[@]}"` and `"$@"`. Also, the `declare` commands are not necessary here. By the way, `app[${#app[@]}]=...` could be abbreviated as `app+=(...)` or even `app+=("$@")` if you leave out the loop.

Comment: For debugging, could you give us the output of `declare -p imgver`?

Comment: I think I figured the issue. Culprit is the whitespace after the word _image:_ asia.gcr.io/lucifer/myapp . so when stored in array of imgver every element after the white-space is considered as a separate value. hence the difference in output when looping. help me figure this out @Socowi on how to do this.

Comment: To convert the lines (including spaces) of `cmd`'s output into an array you can use `mapfile -t array < <(cmd)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @socowi I figured out the issue. When doing declare -p it listed out the variables. and because of the white spaces, the string **image:** was also taken as a separate variable. instead of egrep I opted for awk and I was able to achieve the required output.